# Sort columns containing numbers in numpy text array based on multiple columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

How to sort the following matrix:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([['2', '2', '2', 'd'],
              ['1', '1', '3', 'c'],
              ['1', '13', '1', 'a'],
              ['1', '11', '3', 'b']], dtype='<U2')
```

based on the numbers in the text cells and based on multiple columns? With lists sorting works as follows:

```
sorted([[2, 2, 2, 'd'],
        [1, 1, 3, 'c'],
        [1, 13, 1, 'a'],
        [1, 11, 3, 'b']], key = lambda k: (k[0],k[2],-k[1]))

Out[1]: [[1, 13, 1, 'a'], [1, 11, 3, 'b'], [1, 1, 3, 'c'], [2, 2, 2, 'd']]
```

but how could I sort the numpy array `A` similar to the list above?

First trial was not successful ...

```
sorted(A, key = lambda k: (k[0],k[2],-k[1]))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "< ipython-input-... >", line 1, in 
>       sorted(A, key = lambda k: (k[0],k[2],-k[1]))
>
> TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'numpy.str_'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the sliced values to `int`:

```
sorted(A, key = lambda k: (int(k[0]),int(k[2]),-int(k[1])))

[array(['1', '13', '1', 'a'], dtype='<U2'),
 array(['1', '11', '3', 'b'], dtype='<U2'),
 array(['1', '1', '3', 'c'], dtype='<U2'),
 array(['2', '2', '2', 'd'], dtype='<U2')]
```

Comment: It can't compare strings!! maybe we cant convert that string to integers.

Answer (score 2):

The error says you can't negate `numpy.str_` object sounds logical.
But for solving your problem, I suggest you first sort the array with reverse ordering and key `k[1]` and then sort this result with two other keys.

```
t = sorted(A, key = lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)
t = sorted(t, key = lambda k: (k[0],k[2]))
```

Comment: In this solution one would also need type conversion to `int(k[...])`, as @yatu suggested. The problem was to sort numerically the strings, because alphabetical order does not quarantee numerical order.

Comment: Yes, but I thought you need alphabetical order and maybe you have other than numbers in your strings.